# How can I stop my asp modal popup dialog from closing on button click?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

i wrote a code to show varified as he enters eany data. so i have 2 button to varify and then close. with label to display whether his email id is varified or not...
the code is

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"   PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="btn"  
CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  >
```

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Your Registered Email Id"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2"  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info"  OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Varify"   />



<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
```

code behind code is..

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Visible = true;
        Label2.Text = "Valid User";
        Label2.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showModal()", true);
       // ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
```

but as i click on Button2 it closes the model..then i have to open again to see the output...I want to show the label text with out closing the ModalPopupExtender...Help me

Answer (score 0):

I think postback cause this. I don't know so much about ModalPopupExtender but I can recommend you to use Jquery for button2 click and in click event make an ajax call and check whether your email is valid or not.